# "Всех убью (—) один останусь"

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли поставлено тире в этой поговорке?

Comment: Конечно, лингвистика не место для эмоций. Но какой-то уж очень мрачный пример (((

Answer (score 2):

А я такую поговорку не слышала. Но знаки поставлены верно.  Когда всех убью, то один останусь. Если всех убью,  то один останусь. В любом случае в бессоюзном предложении нужно поставить тире: первая часть содержит указание на время или условие.

Answer (score 1):

Знак поставлен правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Знак поставлен правильно, но уж больно кровожадное высказывание.

Answer (score 0):

вторая часть бессоюзного предложения указывает на следствие, поэтому нужно тире.